# Issue deploying to AppEngine (Flex) from Cloud Build

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

I'm facing issue about deploying to AppEngine Flex Environment via Cloud Build. It used to work fine but not today. here's trace shown on Cloud Build's logs.

```
... (skipped composer's things) ...
Step #1 Updating service [legacy-api] (this may take several minutes)...
Step #1: ..............................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................failed.
Step #1: ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [13] Flex operation projects/MY-PROJECT/regions/asia-east2/operations/... error [INTERNAL]: An internal error occurred while processing task /appengine-flex-v1/insert_flex_deployment/flex_create_resources>2019-11-27T07:24:52.924Z46964.jo.8: Deployment Manager operation …/operation-… errors: [code: "RESOURCE_ERROR"
Step #1: location: "/deployments/…/resources/…-00it"
Step #1: message: "{\"ResourceType\":\"compute.v1.instanceTemplate\",\"ResourceErrorCode\":\"400\",\"ResourceErrorMessage\":{\"code\":400,\"errors\":[{\"domain\":\"global\",\"message\":\"Invalid value for field \'resource.properties.labels\': \'\'. Label value \'Infinity\' violates format constraints. The value can only contain lowercase letters, numeric characters, underscores and dashes. The value can be at most 63 characters long. International characters are allowed.\",\"reason\":\"invalid\"}],\"message\":\"Invalid value for field \'resource.properties.labels\': \'\'. Label value \'Infinity\' violates format constraints. The value can only contain lowercase letters, numeric characters, underscores and dashes. The value can be at most 63 characters long. International characters are allowed.\",\"statusMessage\":\"Bad Request\",\"requestPath\":\"https://compute.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/.../global/instanceTemplates\",\"httpMethod\":\"POST\"}}"
Step #1: ]
```

Here's my cloudbuild.yaml

```
steps:
  - name: 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/secrets:latest'
    entrypoint: sh
    args: 
      - "-c"
      - |
        cat /secrets/$_ENV/environments/${_SERVICE_NAME}.env > .env
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
    args: ["app", "deploy", "--version=$SHORT_SHA", "--promote", "--stop-previous-version", "./app.yaml"]
timeout: 1200s

substitutions:
  _ENV: staging
  _SERVICE_NAME: legacy-api
```

here's my app.yaml

```
service: legacy-api
runtime: php
env: flex

runtime_config:
  document_root: public
  enable_stackdriver_integration: true

resources:
  cpu: 4
  memory_gb: 8

beta_settings:
    cloud_sql_instances: ${CLOUD_SQL_INSTANCE}

network:
  name: default
```

now, this blocked my development processes. please help.

Thanks in advance!

**edit 2019-11-27 23:00 GMT+0700 (12hours after problem first seen)**

things get worse, i have no idea what to do. then, i tried to change deployment destination to Standard Environment. and this is what I get.

```
Starting Step #1
Step #1: Already have image (with digest): gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud
Step #1: Services to deploy:
Step #1: 
Step #1: descriptor:      [/workspace/app.yaml]
Step #1: source:          [/workspace]
Step #1: target project:  [....]
Step #1: target service:  [legacy-api-std]
Step #1: target version:  [201911272240]
Step #1: target url:      [https://legacy-api-std-dot-....appspot.com]
Step #1: 
Step #1: 
Step #1: Do you want to continue (Y/n)?  
Step #1: Beginning deployment of service [legacy-api-std]...
Step #1: Created .gcloudignore file. See `gcloud topic gcloudignore` for details.
Step #1: #============================================================#
Step #1: #= Uploading 1 file to Google Cloud Storage                 =#
Step #1: #============================================================#
Step #1: File upload done.
Step #1: ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) INVALID_ARGUMENT: This deployment has too many files. New versions are limited to 10000 files for this app.
Step #1: - '@type': type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest
Step #1:   fieldViolations:
Step #1:   - description: This deployment has too many files. New versions are limited to 10000
Step #1:       files for this app.
Step #1:     field: version.deployment.files[...]
Finished Step #1
ERROR
ERROR: build step 1 "gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud" failed: exit status 1
```

**update 2019-11-28 08:40:00+0700 (almost 24 hours since the problem first seen**

cases opened in Google Cloud Support 8 hours ago

still no miracle here

Comment: The error is pretty straightforward here, it says that "Deployment Manager operation" failed because `"Invalid value for field \'resource.properties.labels\': \'\'. Label value \'Infinity\' violates format constraints.` You should double check that, changing the label from "Infinity" to "infinity" will remove the error. Also, adding how you are deploying will be good to know here, as I guess that you may be using the Deployment Manager to do so?

Comment: thank you for your answer, I have no idea what the Deployment Manager is and how does it work. all I have is what i posted above. btw, it used to work perfectly until yesterday. any idea? :(

Comment: Did you have a label in your `.env` file? Personally, I think no. This label seems to be an automatic thing from Google and I don't know where is coming. Especially if it works until recently, you should open a case to the support and ask them if there isn't a new release that can block you current deployment.

Comment: It will be also good if you could provide a bit of background about the first step in the cloudbuild.yaml. What does the image 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/secrets:latest' have? Is it just only copying some data to the .env file?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere there's no something like `LABEL` in my `.env`. any other name I should looking for?

Comment: @bhito it just an image that contains `.env` files for the service(s)

Comment: @big, it was my assumption. It sounds like a platform issue. Open a case for this.

Comment: thank you @guillaumeblaquiere, this was made me upset for whole day. to open a case for this, i have to pay $100 to upgrade the support plan. I have no idea if anyone willing to pay for this. but, it seems to be that way :(

Comment: You have the "professional" support, that answer your in less than 4H (for 100$, or less than 1H for 250$) and you have the public support, without any commitment: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues. Select your right topic when you create an issue (appengine flex) and.... wait!

Comment: still no luck :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have been able to find out that the issue is known in GCP and the team is currently working on it.

The error is due to the fact that the SHORT_SHA that you are using, is matching one of the regexs used by the internal Deployment Manager YAML parser. At the moment, this known issue is caused by passing a SHA string that the Deployment Manager YAML parser will evaluate as a float rather than a string, passing a timestamp as a value also causes the parser to incorrectly evaluate the string as a timestamp.

Then adding a random string at the end of the SHORT_SHA will force it to be a string and therefore avoid the issue:

`"${SHORT_SHA}xyz"`

Regex that is being used for floating point numbers can be found [here](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2804092).

I have also created this [PIT](https://issuetracker.google.com/145383056) to keep track of the engineer's investigation. Further information about it will be shared in this thread.